# Block code until event fires (Like modal dialog)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

A modal dialog blocks code until it returns. I want the same thing without the new window.

A simple example with a *separate* dialog (*not* what I'm looking for)

```
MessageBox.Show("Continue");
MessageBox.Show("This waits until the first returns.");
```

A simple *non-working* example of what I'm looking for:

```
mres1.Wait();//Where: ManualResetEventSlim mres1 = new ManualResetEventSlim(false); 
MessageBox.Show("This should wait until button2 is clicked.");
```

+

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mres1.Set();
}
```

Yes, I know this fails because it blocks the whole thread. But that's the kind of system I'm looking for, only without blocking the *thread*, only the *code*. Is that possible?

<sub>(I'm not looking for a workaround (-"Call the rest of the code in the event's event handler."). I'm asking if it can be done as described.)</sub>

**EDIT**: The goal is to replace modal dialogs that I currently have, with a `Panel` (with  `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`).

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2012 or newer?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain VS2010.

Comment: what will be your catalyst to resume execution on the main thread?

Comment: @ispiro If you where using Visual Studio 2012 you can use async/await in .NET 4.0 via [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) which would be perfect for this. But you are not so I am leaving this as a comment instead of a answer.

Comment: @TMcKeown A button click. And there is only one thread. (See question.)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain VS2010. Although - isn't `await` for a second thread anyway? (I'm dealing with only one thread here.)

Comment: @ispiro No, `await` is just waiting for a `Task` to complete without blocking the UI thread. `Tasks` are a wrapper to show some kind of "asynchronous work". That work could be [running a thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), waiting [for a event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or as a wrapper for the old [APM model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (using `BeginXxxx(` and `EndXxxx(`). Tasks (and awaiting) do not mean threads.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly modified version of [SiLo's old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20957967/2) that does not use any extra threads and still works with .NET 4.0

**EDIT**: Updated to use a panel, might need a little more tweaking but I think this will get you 99% of the way there.

```
private TaskCompletionSource<object> waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(); 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Panel coverScreen = new Panel();
    coverScreen.BackColor = Color.Black;
    coverScreen.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(coverScreen);

    waiter.Task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(coverScreen);
        coverScreen.Dispose();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    waiter.SetResult(null);
    waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(); //Reset the TaskCompletionSource
}
```

Comment: @ispiro see the updated version that uses a panel. I think I understand what you are going for and this gets you almost there.

Comment: I like this solution! Didn't even think about manually setting the `Task.Result` to trigger the continuation. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I think I understand your intentions better. Basically, you want to create your own modal behavior instead of using the system default.

In this case you want two separate blocks of code to run, one after the other, and waiting for some user interaction to trigger the transition (such as an `OK` button or `Hide()` method).

Perhaps it would be best to make your own `ModalPanel` UI element that would drive from the base `Panel` control. In your subclass, you could expose a `ShowModal` method that let you put in a task and it would execute once the `ModalPanel` was hidden.

For example:

```
class ModalPanel : Panel
{
    protected readonly Button okButton;
    Task task;

    public ModalPanel()
    {
        okButton = new Button();

        okButton.Width = 100;
        okButton.Height = 32;

        okButton.Left = (this.Width - okButton.Width) / 2;
        okButton.Top = (this.Height - okButton.Height) / 2;

        okButton.Text = "OK";
        okButton.Click += delegate { this.Hide(); };
    }

    public virtual void ShowModal(Task completion)
    {
        this.task = completion;

        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Show();
    }

    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);

        var isHidden = !this.Visible;

        if (isHidden && task != null)
            task.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `SynchronizationContext` ?

Comment: It depends if the OP needs the UI context (if he plans on continuing on it). Will update my answer to include that possibility.

Comment: @L.B (and SiLo) Added an edit (at the end of my question) to clarify.

Comment: How am I supposed to get it to continue when a button is clicked?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But that would be like extracting the continuation-code and calling it from the close button of the Panel (albeit nicer coding of course).

Comment: Ah, I will combine the two... (`Task` and the `EventHandler`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue updating the UI then you should look into the await/async approach however you can wait/signal on non UI threads this way:

If you are partial to the TPL you can use Task<>

```
ManualResetEventSlim mres1 = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( Wait , null );
}

private void Wait(object state)
{
    mres1 = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    mres1.Wait();
    //rest of the code to execute....
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mres1.Set();

}
```

Comment: Not me. I'm still trying it. (It's giving me an error "invalid arguments" at ThreadPool...)

Comment: ok, lemme get signature... this will work, I do this sort of thing all the time.

Comment: @L.B if he is trying to modify the UI then agreed, he will have to invoke on the UI thread. No where did I read he wanted to update the UI.  He should probably use the async if he want's UI

Comment: Added an edit (at the end of my question) to clarify.

Comment: my solution works for you, just incorporate into your new Dialog window.   However like other posters have mentioned, to have your delayed code update the UI you'll need to "invoke" it via the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks. But besides the error I get (see my comment above), I don't want a separate window.

Answer (score -1):

`await`, in combination with a means of converting whatever you want into a task, makes this both easy, clear, and effective.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    button2.Click += (s, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    await tcs.Task;
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Added an edit (at the end of my question) to clarify.

Comment: @ispiro Okay.  That would be easy enough to do using this pattern.

Comment: Is this supposed to work on VS2010/.net4.0? VS doesn't even recognize `async`.

Comment: @ispiro No, it's a .NET 4.5 thing.

Comment: It would work on VS2012 / .NET 4.0 with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. It does require VS2012/VS2013, though.